# Resize and drag component - React Native

Tags: react-native, animation, draggable, pinchzoom

I'm trying to create a draggable and resizeable component in react-native (expo).
The goal is to create HOC component or something like this that allows me to drag and resize images or other child components.
Using {Draggable} from "react-native-draggable" and ImageZoom from "react-native-image-pan-zoom" to wrap my component (image) and try to achieve my goal but with no success.
what am I doing wrong? 
("react-native-drag-resize" not very good, it clumsy)
thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  View, ImageBackground, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { SCREEN_TITLES } from "../../consts/consts";
import ActionBar from "../../components/ActionsBar/ActionBar";
import ImageZoom from "react-native-image-pan-zoom";
import Draggable from "react-native-draggable";

export default class EditConractScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: SCREEN_TITLES.EDIT_CONTRACT,
  });

  state = {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    signature: null,
    clientSignatureDragNDrop: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
    },
  };
  handleSignature = (signature) => {
    this.setState({ signature });
  };
  onLayoutEventHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
      height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
        {/* <Text style={{flex:10}}> edit contract page </Text> */}
        <View style={{ flex: 10 }} onLayout={this.onLayoutEventHandler}>
          <ImageZoom
            cropWidth={this.state.width}
            cropHeight={this.state.height}
            imageWidth={this.state.width}
            imageHeight={this.state.height}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
          >
            <ImageBackground
              style={{ height: this.state.height, width: this.state.width }}
              source={require("../../assets/test.jpg")}
            >
              <Draggable>
                <ImageZoom
                  enableCenterFocus={false}
                  cropWidth={150}
                  cropHeight={150}
                  imageWidth={150}
                  imageHeight={150}
                  style={{ borderWidth: 2 }}
                >
                  <Image
                    resizeMode={"contain"}
                    style={{
                      width: "100%",
                      height: "100%",
                      borderColor: "red",
                    }}
                    source={{ uri: this.state.signature }}
                  />
                </ImageZoom>
              </Draggable>
            </ImageBackground>
          </ImageZoom>
        </View>
        <ActionBar
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          onSign={this.handleSignature}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```